# Android add-on library projects?

Tags: android, add-on

I have a mini piano app on android that I would like to extend with downloadable add-ons.
I would for example have the soundset of a grandpiano as a seperate installable package.

I see some apps that have add-ons (like the NIV Bible, that add different bible editions).
I would like to know how I could integrate a seperate apk add-on into my main program. How can I access those? What would I need to do to integrate these add-ons? Etc.

Any pointers?

**Examples**

The NIV bible has several add-ons in the market that you can download using the market. It looks like these really use the data contained in their packages.

Also, I know that Ruboto uses a ruboto-core package, that contains the JRuby stuff, that gets installed once, and all Ruboto packages rely on that one, so it must be possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that it's possible to access other APK's resources. I don't know if it's limited to apps that have the same signature, that's not something I tried. I do know that you can access other apk's code, since that is wat ruboto is doing with it's ruboto-core package.

To access resources from another installed APK:

```
//Get the other apk's resources
Resources resources = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(
            "package.name.goes.here");

//Then you need to get the ResID
 int resID = resources.getIdentifier(
            "name_goes_here", "string(or other type like raw)", packageName);

//Open stringResource
 String resourceString = resources.getString(resID);
```

This also work with raw resources!